# Autowired bean is null in CGLib proxy

Tags: java, spring, proxy, cglib

I use CGlib proxy for intercept methods in controller and add some behavior for this.
But  I've faced with problem when controller has autowired beans it didn't init and returned as null

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService  service;

    @PostMapping(
            path = "/annotatedEndpoint",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @SessionInfo
    public ResponseEntity checkAnnotation(@RequestBody RequestDto request) {
        SessionResponse response = request.getSessionInfo();
        String test = service.getTestResult();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

In debugger I see that bean' class has inited TestService, but proxy didn't and tests fail with NullPointerException

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) ~[wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ru.info.service.TestController.checkAnnotation(TestController.java:32) ~[test/:na]
    at ru.info.service.TestController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d99acd5.CGLIB$checkAnnotation$0(<generated>) ~[test/:na]
    at ru.info.service.TestController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d99acd5$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f7c281c7.invoke(<generated>) ~[test/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at ru.info.service.SessionMethodInterceptor.intercept(SessionMethodInterceptor.java:43) ~[main/:na]
    at ru.info.service.TestController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d99acd5.checkAnnotation(<generated>) ~[test/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

As I understand proxy is a "subclass" for a target class and I though that it just intercepts methods but uses superclass fields
Could I use superclass inited field, or autowire bean correctly in proxy?

TestService is a just dummy check-component

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestService implements TestServiceInterface {

    public String getTestResult() {
        return "check service";
    }
}
```

Proxy building as

```
Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(beanClass);
        enhancer.setCallback(new SessionMethodInterceptor(sessionService));
        return enhancer.create();
```

Comment: p.s. I know I should use interface or constructor autowiring, I've tried and it got similar result in this case, current implementation just latest which I copied  from IDE

Comment: Could you show your 'TestService'  source code?

Comment: I guess you 'ComponentScan' cann't scan the TestService  class file package

Comment: @Benson no, I 've checked by debugger and  original TestController' bean has populated TestService field, but proxy hasn't

Comment: Could you upload your whole code to github? I want to study it

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's under nda. BeanPostProcessor invoke methods under annotation with changes in the method' arguments. So I guess in this case is using methods from proxy bean and use subclass fields - maybe you know approach to provide inited fields from bean to proxy?

Comment: It cannot be `null` as then your application would fail to start. What I suspect is that either your method or class is `final` or the method you are using is `private` or `default` instead of `public`. Looking at your stacktrace you are actually proxying a proxy, `TestController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d99acd5$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f7c281c`. The question is how are you constructing this? Also it is enhanced by cglib which is weird as it should be proxied by the spring specific CGlib.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In debugger I see that proxy class is a ru.info.service.TestController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d99acd5@16a29eff , to be honest idk what is generated FastClassByCGLIB. I build proxy with enhacher using method interceptor, I'll add this to question

Comment: Why? Let Spring do that for you. You are creating a proxy for a class that is already a proxy, instead let Spring apply the interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've figured out how it can be resolved

I should pass  original bean to interceptor

```
 public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (classesWithAnnotatedMethods.get(beanName) != null) {
            Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
            enhancer.setSuperclass(bean.getClass());
            enhancer.setCallback(new SessionMethodInterceptor(bean));
            return enhancer.create();
        }
        return bean;
    }
```

And in the interceptor:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SessionMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {     
private final Object originalBean;

        @Override
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
           // * args' changes *
            return method.invoke(originalBean, args);
        }
```